# Assign values to variables using a loop (set_fact or other?)

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Using an Ansible task, I'm trying to create variables and associated values from a returned loop object.
Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

```yaml
- name: Get values
  someModule: 
    input_from_loop: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - "foo"
    - "bar"
  register: get_result
```

Gives

```yaml
get_result:
  changed: false  
  msg: All items completed
  results:
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    item: foo
    alpha:
      beta:
        content: someFooValue
  - ansible_loop_var: item
    item: bar
    alpha:
      beta:
        content: someBarValue
```

With this `get_result` object, I'm trying to create variables and associated values such that:

**Pseudocode:**

```yaml
- name: Assign values
  set_fact:
    "{{ item.item }}":"{{ item.alpha.beta.content }}"
  loop: get_result.results
```

To result in:

```
foo:someFooValue
bar:someBarValue
```

I can't seem to get around the error

> Implicit map keys need to be followed by map values"
> I do not want to create a new object, just variables with values for later use (in existing tasks).

I've tried a few approaches to no avail.

[Or can it happen on each iteration of the initial loop calling the module?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I am rereading your your requirements, I am wondering if you are not looking for variables at the top level of your host that would be named

- `foo` and contain `someFooValue`
- `bar` and contain `someBarValue`

If this is the case, then most of that is above does still apply, the registering of the fact only change:

```yaml
- set_fact: { "{{ item.0 }}": "{{ item.1 }}" }
  loop: "{{
      get_result.results | map(attribute='item') | zip(
        get_result.results | map(attribute='alpha.beta.content')
      )
    }}"
```

Which gives you the two expected variables with the corresponding values.

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  foo: someFooValue

ok: [localhost] => 
  bar: someBarValue
```

---

What you can do in those kind of cases is to break down the dictionary in multiple lists, all containing one of the field you are interested into, with the `map` filter, then reconstruct a list of list with the help of the `zip` filter. And finally, join everything together.

So, with a task like:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    formatted_fact: "{{
        get_result.results | map(attribute='item') | zip(
          get_result.results | map(attribute='alpha.beta.content')
        ) | map('join', ':') | join('\n')
      }}"
```

You get your expected output:

```yaml
formatted_fact: |-
  foo:someFooValue
  bar:someBarValue
```

---

Given those couple of tasks, we have the two possibilities:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    formatted_fact: "{{
        get_result.results | map(attribute='item') | zip(
          get_result.results | map(attribute='alpha.beta.content')
        ) | map('join', ':') | join('\n')
      }}"
  vars:
    get_result:
      changed: false
      msg: All items completed
      results:
      - ansible_loop_var: item
        item: foo
        alpha:
          beta:
            content: someFooValue
      - ansible_loop_var: item
        item: bar
        alpha:
          beta:
            content: someBarValue

- debug:
    var: formatted_fact

- set_fact: { "{{ item.0 }}": "{{ item.1 }}" }
  loop: "{{
      get_result.results | map(attribute='item') | zip(
        get_result.results | map(attribute='alpha.beta.content')
      )
    }}"
  vars:
    get_result:
      changed: false
      msg: All items completed
      results:
      - ansible_loop_var: item
        item: foo
        alpha:
          beta:
            content: someFooValue
      - ansible_loop_var: item
        item: bar
        alpha:
          beta:
            content: someBarValue

- debug:
    var: foo

- debug:
    var: bar
```

They would yield:

```
TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  formatted_fact: |-
    foo:someFooValue
    bar:someBarValue

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['foo', 'someFooValue'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['bar', 'someBarValue'])

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  foo: someFooValue

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  bar: someBarValue
```

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
_query: '[].{key: item, value: alpha.beta.content}'
result: "{{ get_result.results|json_query(_query)|items2dict }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
result:
  bar: someBarValue
  foo: someFooValue
```

---

Example of a complete playbook (for testing)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    get_result:
      changed: false  
      msg: All items completed
      results:
      - ansible_loop_var: item
        item: foo
        alpha:
          beta:
            content: someFooValue
      - ansible_loop_var: item
        item: bar
        alpha:
          beta:
            content: someBarValue

    _query: '[].{key: item, value: alpha.beta.content}'
    result: "{{ get_result.results|json_query(_query)|items2dict }}"

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: result
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question in the headline

> *How to assign values to variables using a loop (set_fact)?*

and the mentioned "pseudocode" I like to note that such approach might work, as the following test

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    varKey: "TEST"
    varVal: "testValue"

  tasks:

  - name: Create variable dynamic
    set_fact:
       "{{ varKey }}_{{ item }}": "{{ varVal }}_{{ item }}"
    loop: [1, 2, 3]

  - name: Show variable
    debug:
      var: TEST_{{ item }}
    loop: ["1", "2", "3"]
```

results into an output of

```yaml
TASK [Create variable dynamic] *********
ok: [localhost] => (item=1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=3)

TASK [Show variable] *********
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  TEST_1: testValue_1
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: '1'
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  TEST_2: testValue_2
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: '2'
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  TEST_3: testValue_3
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: '3'
```

and also

```yaml
  - name: Create variable dynamic
    set_fact:
       "{{ item }}": "{{ item }}"
    loop: [A1, A2, A3]

  - name: Show variable
    debug:
      var: "{{ item }}"
    loop: [A1, A2, A3]
```

into

```yaml
TASK [Create variable dynamic] **********
ok: [localhost] => (item=A1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=A2)
ok: [localhost] => (item=A3)

TASK [Show variable] **********
ok: [localhost] => (item=A1) =>
  A1: A1
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: A1
ok: [localhost] => (item=A2) =>
  A2: A2
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: A2
ok: [localhost] => (item=A3) =>
  A3: A3
  ansible_loop_var: item
  item: A3
```